# Combining Gradient boosted trees after multiple imputation

Tags: boosting, multiple-imputation

Currently I am working with a gradient boosted tree model fit onto a multiple imputed dataset.

For those who don't know multiple imputation: 
It predicts missing values and imputes that value with added noise. 
It does this m times and thus creates m data sets. 
These data sets are then analyzed separately and their results are combined into one result.

Now I have used a gradient boosted tree to build a classifier. 
This results in m separate boosted models. 
However I cannot find a way to combine these. In regression one would simply average the regression coefficients.

I have looked at these, but they don't give me any clues as how to pool these models.

[Reconciling boosted regression trees (BRT), generalized boosted models (GBM), and gradient boosting machine (GBM)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149701/reconciling-boosted-regression-trees-brt-generalized-boosted-models-gbm-an)
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/quick-introduction-boosting-algorithms-machine-learning/
[Gradient in Gradient Boosting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338658/gradient-in-gradient-boosting)

This one is about combining trees, but not in a way that is useful for my situation.

[Combine decision trees from GBM to reduce output](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100392/combine-decision-trees-from-gbm-to-reduce-output)

The question:

Is there a way to combine these gradient boosted tree based models into one?